# Python OpenCV how to save an image after transforming it

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am new to python.  I am using opencv to tranform an image.
Below are the two last lines in the script:

```
warped = warped.astype("uint8") * 255
cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))
```

I would like to save the warped image as a jpeg file.
How do I go about it?

Comment: Have you tried `cv2.imwrite()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First hold the modified image in a variable, then use the following command:

```
cv2.imwrite("IMAGE_NAME.png", warpedimage)
```