# Rewrite Image after applying sharpening filter to it

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have to sharpen an image and use it for further process.I found a code based on OpenCv which would do the work but instead of just displaying I want to save the image after applying the affects.Also this is just for a single image I want to apply for a folder of images. The sharpening code is below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Reading in and displaying our image
image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Original', image)
# Create our shapening kernel, it must equal to one eventually
kernel_sharpening = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], 
                              [-1, 9,-1],
                              [-1,-1,-1]])
# applying the sharpening kernel to the input image & displaying it.
sharpened = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel_sharpening)
cv2.imshow('Image Sharpening', sharpened)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python OpenCV how to save an image after transforming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367228/python-opencv-how-to-save-an-image-after-transforming-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
cv2.imwrite('images/input.jpg', image)
```

after

```
sharpened = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel_sharpening)
```

and something like:

```
for im_path in im_paths:
   image = cv2.imread(im_path)
   ...
```

where you just replace your hardcoded path with `im_path`.

Anyway this is fundamental research, [for example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html), and you should apply this before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#write-an-image):

> Write an image Use the function cv2.imwrite() to save an image.
>
> First argument is the file name, second argument is the image you want
>   to save.
>
> cv2.imwrite('messigray.png',img)